# Evaluating derivatives with Let f(x) = 3, f'(x) = 1

Tags: derivatives

Let f(x) = 3, f'(x) = 1 g(x) = 10  g'(x) = 7 then evaluate

$$\lim_{x\to x_o}[{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} -\frac{f(x_o)}{g(x_o)}\over x-x_o} ]$$

What does this mean? And hpw to do it in full workout please

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the derivative of a differentiable function $h(x)$ is defined as 
$$ h'(x_0) := \lim_{x\to x_0} {h(x) - h(x_0) \over x - x_0}. $$

So in your example you want to calculate the derivative of $f(x)/g(x)$.
This is easy if you may use the [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule):
$$ {d \over dx} {f(x) \over g(x)} = {g(x)f'(x) - g'(x)f(x) \over g(x)^2}. $$
In your example this equals: $$ {10 \cdot 1 - 3 \cdot 7 \over 10^2}. $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please consider not writing out such a detailed and complete answer to a question that is missing a lot of context or details from the OP.